# Where does Workbench deploy to?

Tags: workbench

After a few months pause, I am using Workbench again and I cannot determine where is WB sending (deploying) my built package. WB does not ask for a destination folder, so I guess it must use some preference I set before... only I do not remember it!
So, can someone please tell me how to find/set the destination folder for deployed applications? (Searching on my HDDs takes a long time.)

Comment: If you want more control over things, you can use Apache Ant (or any other build tool, but Ant is integrated into WB) to build the project yourself, and deploy it whereever you like. This is less relevant for a single package, but can be very useful for more complex projects containing several packages, and possibly code in other languages (C/C++/Java/etc). It also is useful when you have paclet documentation, since you may include documentation build as a part of your build process, and have a single build/deploy process then.

Comment: thank you @Leonid.I have no experience with Ant (yet), but this is the second time you mentioned it, while answering to one of my questions. I guess it is high time to have a look at it :-)

Comment: While Ant has traditionally been more a tool used by professional Java devs (I was in that capacity for a short time, so was lucky to pick it up there), it is a generally useful tool. It is very easy to learn. You write a couple of build scripts and it becomes your friend. In Mathematica, it is also used in quite interesting ways, since it is augmented by Mathematica task, so Ant in fact launches the M kernel for certain builds (such as e.g. Documentation build), and some parts of the build are performed by Mathematica (it can be seen by inspecting  documentation build component in WB).

Comment: I wish to report the following bug in WB: if you use WB and MMA on Windows on a non-English system, the "Application Data" folder has a different name (it gets translated). MMA takes this into account with BaseDirectory and  UserBaseDirectory, but WB keeps using "Application Data" as the name of the folder with its BaseDirectory and  UserBaseDirectory checkboxes. That's why I could not find my package at first. Maybe this bug exists also with other OS

Comment: I never experienced this, since I only worked with the English version. You can send an email to WRI tech.support, explaining the problem.

Answer (score 10):

The default directory is `$UserAddOnsDirectory/Applications` and in MacOSX and Linux you see the target folder every time you click on *Deploy Application*.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the very rapid answer (< 4 minutes).

Comment: What happens when you have a `Kernel/init.m` file in your package folder? Is it the same as having the commands in your global `init.m`, but loaded only when you load the package?

Comment: @R.M When you would call ``<<DrosteEffect` `` for the above package, you have to notice, that this is a folder you try to load. The *correct* way would be to make ``<<DrosteEffect`DrosteEffect` ``. The usual way is to put this `Get` into the `init.m`, because this file is loaded if the parameter for `Get` is a folder. Look up the doc to `Get`: "If the file found by <<name is a directory, Mathematica will try to load the file  in that directory."

Comment: @R.M. To add to the comment of halirutan, `init.m` in larger projects with non-trivial directory structure/layout, serves to 1. Enable Mathematica to locate this project, since `Get` looks also for folders with the name matching the context name and having `init.m` in them,  2. Make the mapping from context name to file name more flexible  3.(related)Give the developer more freedom to perform initialization steps. In particular, you can use `init.m` to load contexts to be used by their shorter names, which would otherwise require a longer name (e.g. like in the example mentioned by halirutan).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin and Halirutan, thanks for the explanations. I haven't used mma for large projects, but I probably will soon enough, and this is good to know